# Sorting a query on the sum of 2 columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails 2.3.8 I'm trying to order a query having first the post that has the most comments AND votes.

I've tried to add a new method to the Post model as:

```
def interestingness
  self.comments_count + self.votes_count
end  

post_of_the_moment = find(:all,   :conditions => ["submitted_at BETWEEN ? and ?", from, to],
                          :order      => :interestingness,
                          :limit      => 10
                           )
```

but this code gives me a Unknown column error.

I also tried this

```
post_of_the_moment = find(:all,   :conditions => ["submitted_at BETWEEN ? and ?", from, to],
                          :order      => "SUM(comments_count+votes_count) DESC",
                          :limit      => 10
                           )
```

this doesn't give me errors but puts as result only 1 row that has 0 comments and 0 votes.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Augusto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  post_of_the_moment = find(:all, :select => '*, comments_count + votes_count AS total', :conditions => ["submitted_at BETWEEN ? and ?", from, to], :order  => "total DESC", :limit => 10)
```

I'd also see if you can optimize it be replacing the * above with only the fields you actually need. Also check your MySQL indexes are ok, as you want to avoid a full table scan etc. to sum the counts.

Comment: The reason your first attempt won't work is because 'interestingness' is only calculated after the database query. The database itself is unaware of your model - it's only aware of the columns you have defined in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the error I was doing: the SUM() in the order was grouping the result set.

This works:

```
post_of_the_moment = find(:all,   :conditions => ["submitted_at BETWEEN ? and ?", from, to],
                      :order      => "(comments_count+votes_count) DESC",
                      :limit      => 10
                       )
```

Still don't know why I cannot use as a sort field the interestingness method I created.

Comment: interestingness is a Ruby method, but find queries the database. The database doesn't know about anything in the Ruby world.